# Load a single image in a pretrained pytorch net

Tags: python, deep-learning, image-segmentation, pytorch, conv-neural-network

Total newbie here, I'm using [this](https://github.com/delta-onera/segnet_pytorch/blob/master/segnet.py) pytorch SegNet implementation with a '.pth' file containing weights from a 50 epochs training.
How can I load a single test image and see the net prediction?
I know this may sound like a stupid question but I'm stuck.
What I've got is:

```
from segnet import SegNet
import torch

model = SegNet(2)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load('./model_segnet_epoch50.pth'))
```

How do I "use" the net on a single test picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`output = model(image)`
.

Note that the image should be a `Variable` object and that the output will be as well.
If your image is, for example, a Numpy array, you can convert it like so:

`var_image = Variable(torch.Tensor(image))`

Comment: Note: Variable was [deprecated in PyTorch 0.4](https://pytorch.org/blog/pytorch-0_4_0-migration-guide/).

Answer (score 6):

I provide with an example of `ResNet152` pre-trained model.

```
def image_loader(loader, image_name):
    image = Image.open(image_name)
    image = loader(image).float()
    image = torch.tensor(image, requires_grad=True)
    image = image.unsqueeze(0)
    return image

data_transforms = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize(256),
    transforms.CenterCrop(224),
    transforms.ToTensor()
])


model_ft = models.resnet152(pretrained=True)
model_ft.eval()

print( np.argmax(model_ft(image_loader(data_transforms, $FILENAME)).detach().numpy()))
```

`$FILENAME` is the path and name of your image to be loaded. I got necessary help from this [post](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-classify-single-image-using-loaded-net/1411/2?u=tengerye).

Comment: how do you do this with your own model you wrote?

Comment: @joehoeller Not sure what you mean exactly. Couldn't you assign your model to `model_ft`?